# @Override command is not compatible with 'Ready to Program Java?'

Tags: java, swing, overriding

Apparently @Override is a **Illegal Token**

How can I get by this, is it possible?

EDIT:

*My apologies. I did not know that Ready to Program is java v. 1.4. I am a novice and thought initially that java language vocabulary is universal and only the classes change though version changes.*

Comment: Which JDK are you using? Paste the exact and complete compiler error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking it up, the thing you're using ("Ready to program Java") comes with **Java 1.4**. It's *ancient*.

So ... no, `@Override` isn't allowed, and also you can not set the layout directly on the `JFrame`.

See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setLayout(java.awt.LayoutManager)

> By default the layout of this component may not be set, the layout of
>   its contentPane should be set instead. For example: 
>   thisComponent.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2))
>
> An
>   attempt to set the layout of this component will cause an runtime
>   exception to be thrown. Subclasses can disable this behavior.

Comment: Thankyou. I guess I will be using eclipse from now on.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't set the layout directly on the JFrame. As the Error says '`use Project1.getContentPane().setLayout() instead`'.

It would be better to add a JPanel to the JFrame first, then add all of you items to the JPanel. You would also only change the layout manager on the JPanel, not on the JFrame

Comment: Actually, `frame.setLayout()` and `frame.add()` both will be delegated and invoked on the `contentPane` of the `JFrame` (which is a `JPanel`). I am not sure why such error occurs.

Comment: Actually - if you look it up, it's because the thing he's using comes with Java 1.4; it's *ancient*